# Can we update ddl sql command or script by code

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Can we  update ddl sql  command or script by code.

I want to add some constraint in sql table  through code in accumatica.....can we have option to call script by code or can we run sql table DDL commands by code in graph.

Comment: what is the goal of the constraint? ideally there should be no logic in SQL and all logic in the graph.

Comment: I  want to update some ddl script when customization plugin is published by code.